# Cannot access internal network server from internal network device using public IP

Tags: networking, router, ssh, nat

[image: network figure.]

I cannot access server2 from my laptop under the office network using public external IP address.

And here is my experiment

| Case | From | To | Command | Connection |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Case 1 | L | server1 | ssh server1@1.2.3.4 -p 4001 | OK |
| Case 2 | L | server1 | ssh server1@192.168.1.10 -p 4001 | OK |
| **Case 3** | **L** | **server2** | **ssh server2@1.2.3.4 -p 2001** | **Time out** |
| Case 4 | L | server2 | ssh server2@192.168.1.11 -p 2001 | OK |
| Case 5 | D | server1 | ssh server1@1.2.3.4 -p 4001 | OK |
| Case 6 | D | server2 | ssh server2@1.2.3.4 -p 2001 | OK |

I saw the same situations on another laptop.

I got some hint that NAT hairpin should be supported in my router (Linksys mx5500).

But I found that my router supported it. I found the checkbox 'Filter NAT internal redirection' in 192.168.1.1 and it was already unchecked.

I thought this was due to a firewall or incorrect IP settings, but based on my experiments, this is not possible.

Comment: Run a `tcpdump -n -i any "port 2001"` packet capture on the server; what does it see during connection attempts?

Comment: @u1686_grawity Sorry to late. The command shows many lines because it is office servers, but the lines related this problem doesn't show up. In other words, I typed `ssh server2@1.2.3.4 -p 2001` in my labtop and check the server monitor. But the lines containing 192.168.1.39, which is my labtop internal ip, didn't show up until "Connection time out" shows up on my labtop.

Comment: Since you're using the external IP to connect, would the server be seeing your laptop's internal IP?

Comment: @Xen2050: In this case I would expect it to be seeing the _router's_ IP instead, but that's purely because of the "NAT hairpin" workaround – if it weren't for that, then it would be completely normal for the server to see the laptop's internal address, since all traffic is still within the network boundary.

Comment: @Olivia: Do you mean they didn't show up at all, or do you mean they did show up but independently from the SSH connection attempt? I assume the other output means the rest of the office is successfully connecting to `-p 2001` on that same server?

Comment: @u1686_grawity: Ah, they didn't show up at all. In office there are other devices. They are communicating with server2 using internal IP because of the issue, so the server2 CLI shows many lines about them.
For your comment, I disconnected all connections to server2 from my laptop, tried to access it using public IP, and ran `tcpdump -n -i any "port 2001"` in the server2. The result is that the server2 didn't show any lines related with my IP.

Comment: Right, but because of the way "NAT hairpin" works, it will deliberately _hide_ your laptop's IP (as that is exactly what "breaks" LAN-to-LAN port-forwarding) and it'll probably show the router's IP instead, so it's going to be hard to distinguish from the other office users if there is other activity. It would probably be easier if you could also set up e.g. port 2002 for test purposes

Comment: I resolved this issue by resetting the router and all network settings... Even though I couldn't figure out what was causing the problem, I appreciate all the kind responses.